# Oracle SQL function problems

Tags: oracle, plsql

Recently i've picked up Oracle SQL, Right now i'm trying to write a function that later will be used in a view to generate a list. but for now im stuck on the function itself...

The function makes use of the table `EVENTS` with the colum '`NAME`, if the user given name that is implemented into the function is not found it should return 'UNKNOWN' else it should just return the given value(as it was shown in `EVENTS.NAME`.

So this is what i got, but it always returns `'UNKNOWN'`

```
 create or replace FUNCTION W_2_F(P_eventsName varchar2) 
return varchar2 is 
temp_eventName varchar2(50) := P_eventsName;

 BEGIN
  SELECT EVENTS.NAME into temp_eventName
  FROM EVENTS
  WHERE EVENTS.NAME = P_eventsName;

  EXCEPTION 
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND then temp_eventName := 'UNKNOWN';

 RETURN temp_eventName;
 end;
```

I've been trying to fix it for a while now, but it just wont return the right value

Comment: `I'm trying to write a function that later will be used in a view to generate a list` .... why not simply incorporate the logic in this function directly into the view by performing a left join to the events table? I'm guessing that your select is failing because of case sensitivity issues - in Oracle, `'a'` is not the same as `'A'`. Without more details (such as sample data from your table and the values you're passing into the function) it's difficult to say.

Comment: It's really hard to answer without some sample data and/or the code calling your function. As far as we know, your table could be completely empty, or you could call the function with a null string. Please try to build a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the surgestions both, i've gotten it working now. Next time i'll provide more info in my question(s). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the function as written, calls with a value in `EVENTS.NAME` result in `ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value`. That behavior is different than what you are reporting.

The problem is that the only return statement is in the exception block. The indentation to match what is happening would look like:

```
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        temp_eventName := 'UNKNOWN';
        RETURN temp_eventName; 
END;
```

To fix, create another level of nesting, assigning the return value in inner block and returning in outer block:

```
create or replace FUNCTION W_2_F(P_eventsName varchar2) return varchar2 is 
    temp_eventName varchar2(50) := P_eventsName;
BEGIN
    BEGIN 
        SELECT EVENTS.NAME into temp_eventName
        FROM EVENTS
        WHERE EVENTS.NAME = P_eventsName;
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        temp_eventName := 'UNKNOWN';
    END;
    RETURN temp_eventName;
END;
```

Comment: Solved it, it seems to work even with the view now :) thanks!